# How can I deduce from a graph the formula of a parabola with $(h,k)$ vertex?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I want to deduce the formula of a parabola with $(h,k)$ vertex from a graph. So far I only could deduce the formula of one with $(0,0)$ vertex, by doing this:

[image]

$\color{red}{p1}:\, D=D'$

$\color{red}{p2}:\, \sqrt{x^2+(y-c)^2}=y+c$

$\color{red}{p3}:\, x^2+(y-c)^2=(y+c)^2$

$\color{red}{p4}:\, x^2+y^2-2yc+c^2=y^2+2yc+c^2$

$\color{red}{\therefore} \, x^2=4cy$

I already built a graph for the one with $(h,k)$ vertex:

[image]

But, so far, I have only come up with this deduction, and I don't even know if it's right

$\color{red}{p1}:\, D=D'$

$\color{red}{p2}:\, \sqrt{(x-h)^2+(y-2c-k)^2}=y-k+c$

I already know that the formula is $\mathbf{(x-h)^2=4c(y-k)}$, but I want to know how one gets there. So how can I finish the deduction that I have so far, if what it has is correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean $(x - h)^2 = 4c(y - k)$?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make [the translation of axes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_of_axes) represented by the equations $x'=x-h$ and $y'=y-k$, then a parabola with vertex $(x,y)=(h,k)$ becomes a parabola with vertex $(x',y')=(0,0)$ in the $x',y'$-coordinate system, whose formula, $x'^2=4cy'$, you have already deduced. Consequently, $$(x-h)^2=4c(y-k)$$ is the equation of the parabola in the $x,y$-coordinate system.

*Added*: In the second picture the difference in the $y$ coordinates of $P$ and $F$ is $y-c-k$ instead of $y-2c-k$. So your last equation should be
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{(x-h)^{2}+(y-c-k)^{2}}=y-k+c.
\end{equation*}

Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x-h)^{2}+(y-k-c)^{2} &=&\left( y-k+c\right) ^{2} \\
(x-h)^{2}+(y-k)^{2}-2c(y-k)+c^{2} &=&(y-k)^{2}+2c(y-k)+c^{2} \\
(x-h)^{2}-2c(y-k) &=&2c(y-k) \\
(x-h)^{2} &=&4c(y-k),
\end{eqnarray*}
as above.

Comment: Friend; thank you, sincerely.

Comment: @DanielBonillaJaramillo glad to help!